# Uniquely identify albums and songs in Windows Phone media library

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-library

I am importing a songs collection from an `Album` object that is obtained from querying `MediaLibrary` on Windows Phone Mango.

Is there a unique identifier provided by the platform, by which I could be identifying different songs and albums?

I need something that will remain the same for the same albums if I re-query the `MediaLibrary` next time my app is ran.

I have seen a "handle" property in the debugger, but it doesn't appear in any of the Album class documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try `GetHashCode()` for `Song` and `Album`. At least `Song` overrides this function directly, so hopefully it is computed from the song's properties.